# How can we create several lines using a loop in a kv file? (Python3, kivy)

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, kivy, line

I'm just learning to code and I'm discovering kivy. I want to draw a grid using kivy language.
The syntaxe of drawing a line is:

```
<Frontend>:
    canvas:
        Line:
            points: x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2
```

So I've decided to proceed the same way as if I was using Tkinter.
As I've found, we can iterate widgets with kivy language. At least, it works with Labels.

```
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
<Frontend>:
    on_parent:
        for i in range(3): self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Hello world'))
```

Meanwhile when I've tried to do the same thing with lines, it raised different errors, that seem to be logical, as we find Lines in kivy.graphics and other widgets in kivy.uix.

Nevertheless I've tried that (last try):

```
#:import ins kivy.graphics.instructions
#:import v kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions

<Frontend>:
    on_parent:
        for i in range(3): ins.Canvas.add(v.Line(points=(x_1, x_1, x_2, x_2)))
```

I've also tried "draw", but the two raised the same error: "descriptor 'add' for 'kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas' objects doesn't apply to a 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Line' object".

So maybe it's impossible to create a grid thit way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#:import Line kivy.graphics.Line
<Frontend>:
    pts: [100, 100, 500, 100,   100, 200, 500, 200,    100, 300, 500, 300]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
    on_parent:
        for i in range(0, len(root.pts), 4): self.canvas.add(Line(points=root.pts[i:i+4]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exactly that I want, though I'm not shure to understand what was my error when I tryed to do something similar without a list of points.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. There are a few options off the top of my head you could try.

1. Correction: It seems that you have a syntax error. If you are adding a new widget, you indent. If you are carrying out a function (in this case), you code on the same line with the callback. Also, turning from a tenery operation to [lambda function](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#arguments).

```
<Frontend>:
    on_parent: lambda *a: tuple(self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello world')) for i in range(3))
#Put it in line
```

2. Factory: The previous code may not work. The kivy way of adding children is using the `Factory` class.

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Frontend>:
    on_parent: lambda *a: tuple(self.add_widget(Factory.Label(text='Hello world')) for i in range(3))
```

3. Sadly, neither of these may work. The best solution is to create a [custom widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html#add-a-color-to-the-background-of-a-custom-layouts-rule-class) and define the logic within the widget in python. Use the builtin callbacks([for example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.html#initializing-focus)).

```
class CustomLayout(GridLayout):
def on_parent(self, *args):
    for i in range(3):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello world"))
```